# Setting an app to output ALL audio on a single channel

Tags: android

I want to be able to play all audio from one app on only one channel on a device e.g only on left speakers.

I can do this with MediaPlayer playing an mp3 file like this to play only on left speaker

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.bitter_sweet);
mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 0f);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

But I want ALL audio from the app to play on left speaker, i.e if i add a webview and load a youtube url the audio should still play on one channel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Exoplayer I can achieve this by creating a custom AudioProcessor adopted from the [ChannelMappingAudioProcessor](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/e87e231/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/audio/ChannelMappingAudioProcessor.java)

```
public class StereoVolumeProcessor implements AudioProcessor {

private int channelCount;
private int sampleRateHz;
private int[] pendingOutputChannels;

private boolean active;
private int[] outputChannels;
private ByteBuffer buffer;
private ByteBuffer outputBuffer;
private boolean inputEnded;

private float[] volume;

private static final int LEFT_SPEAKER = 0;
private static final int RIGHT_SPEAKER = 1;

public StereoVolumeProcessor() {
    buffer = EMPTY_BUFFER;
    outputBuffer = EMPTY_BUFFER;
    channelCount = Format.NO_VALUE;
    sampleRateHz = Format.NO_VALUE;
}

public void setChannelMap(int[] outputChannels) {
    pendingOutputChannels = outputChannels;
}

@Override
public boolean configure(int sampleRateHz, int channelCount, @C.Encoding int encoding)
        throws UnhandledFormatException {
    if(volume == null){
        throw new IllegalStateException("volume has not been set! Call setVolume(float left,float right)");
    }

    boolean outputChannelsChanged = !Arrays.equals(pendingOutputChannels, outputChannels);
    outputChannels = pendingOutputChannels;
    if (outputChannels == null) {
        active = false;
        return outputChannelsChanged;
    }
    if (encoding != C.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT) {
        throw new UnhandledFormatException(sampleRateHz, channelCount, encoding);
    }
    if (!outputChannelsChanged && this.sampleRateHz == sampleRateHz
            && this.channelCount == channelCount) {
        return false;
    }
    this.sampleRateHz = sampleRateHz;
    this.channelCount = channelCount;

    active = true;
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
}

@Override
public int getOutputChannelCount() {
    return outputChannels == null ? channelCount : outputChannels.length;
}

@Override
public int getOutputEncoding() {
    return C.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
}

/**
 * Returns the sample rate of audio output by the processor, in hertz. The value may change as a
 * result of calling {@link #configure(int, int, int)} and is undefined if the instance is not
 * active.
 */
@Override
public int getOutputSampleRateHz() {
    return sampleRateHz;
}

@Override
public void queueInput(ByteBuffer inputBuffer) {
    int position = inputBuffer.position();
    int limit = inputBuffer.limit();
    int size = limit - position;

    if (buffer.capacity() < size) {
        buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    } else {
        buffer.clear();
    }

    if(isActive()){
        int ch = 0;
        for(int i = position;i<limit;i+=2){
            short sample = (short) (inputBuffer.getShort(i)* volume[ch++]);
            buffer.putShort(sample);
            ch%=channelCount;
        }
    }else{
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }

    inputBuffer.position(limit);
    buffer.flip();
    outputBuffer = buffer;
}

@Override
public void queueEndOfStream() {
    inputEnded = true;
}

/**
 * Sets the volume of right and left channels/speakers
 * The values are between 0.0 and 1.0
 *
 * @param left
 * @param right
 */
public void setVolume(float left,float right){
    volume = new float[]{left,right};
}

public float getLeftVolume(){
    return volume[LEFT_SPEAKER];
}

public float getRightVolume(){
    return volume[RIGHT_SPEAKER];
}

@Override
public ByteBuffer getOutput() {
    ByteBuffer outputBuffer = this.outputBuffer;
    this.outputBuffer = EMPTY_BUFFER;
    return outputBuffer;
}

@SuppressWarnings("ReferenceEquality")
@Override
public boolean isEnded() {
    return inputEnded && outputBuffer == EMPTY_BUFFER;
}

@Override
public void flush() {
    outputBuffer = EMPTY_BUFFER;
    inputEnded = false;
}

@Override
public void reset() {
    flush();
    buffer = EMPTY_BUFFER;
    channelCount = Format.NO_VALUE;
    sampleRateHz = Format.NO_VALUE;
    outputChannels = null;
    active = false;
}
```

}

Volume can be set with a value between 0.0 and 1.0 on either left, right or both speakers.

Use the processor as follows

```
stereoVolumeProcessor = new StereoVolumeProcessor();
stereoVolumeProcessor.setChannelMap(new int[]{0,1});
stereoVolumeProcessor.setVolume(1,0);
RenderersFactory factory = new DefaultRenderersFactory(this){
        /**
         * Builds an array of {@link AudioProcessor}s that will process PCM audio before output.
         */
        @Override
        protected AudioProcessor[] buildAudioProcessors() {
            return new AudioProcessor[] {stereoVolumeProcessor};
        }
    };
```

Comment: How would you make it play 1 channel from both earbuds?
For example I want to hear only left channel, but through both earbuds, and then switch to hearing two at the same time again

Comment: @laszlo I have found a solution from here https://gist.github.com/l0rn/1c4808f260161d7a486277bdf50d008d
You might need to pass new variables to the renderer instead of changing a new renderers

Comment: In my case just call a setVolume with a new left, right again